# OSX SSH to server through SOCKS5 proxy

Tags: macos, ssh, proxy, socks

I am trying to connect to a server through a SOCKS5 proxy. I've tried using -o and editing my ~/.ssh/config file but to no avail.

Here is the SSH command I've tried:

`ssh -v -o 'ProxyCommand=nc -X 5 -x proxyhost:1080 %h %p' -p22 username@serverhost`

The problem seems to be that my proxyhost requires a username and password and I cannot see how to pass the user/pass in the ProxyCommand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the username and password to `nc` command, who is doing your proxy. All about it is written in manual page for [`ncat(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ncat):

> `--proxy-auth user[:pass]` (Specify proxy credentials) .
>
> In connect mode, gives the credentials that will be used to connect to the proxy server. In listen mode, gives the credentials that will be required of connecting clients. For use with **--proxy-type http**, the form should be user:pass. For **--proxy-type socks4**, it should be a username only.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this'll work... ncat supports http connect and socks4 proxy -- not socks5. I'll look for an OSX version of ncat but as documented it doesn't support socks5.

On OSX, nc is the netcat tool, supports socks5, but doesn't seem to support proxy auth

Comment: UPDATE: success (at last)

Earlier versions of ncat didn't support socks5 (and man pages online are older) but v7+ does...

1. ncat isn't available on OSX by default and isn't directly in homebrew you can `brew install nmap` to get the popular network scanner application and the install includes ncat with support for socks5

2. The ssh string (or ~/.ssh/config) should be:

`ssh -v -o 'ProxyCommand=ncat --proxy-type socks5 --proxy proxyhost:proxyport --proxy-auth proxyuser:proxypass %h %p' -p22 username@serverhost`